# Alternative to .htaccess compression with Boost

Tags: performance, .htaccess, caching

My hosting provider doesn't support [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_deflate.html) directives in .htaccess to provide compressed HTTP responses.

I am using Drupal 7 with [Boost](http://drupal.org/project/boost) and wish to compress HTML, CSS and JS responses.

Is there another alternative to doing this with .htaccess?

Comment: Hopefully @mikeytown2 will see this as I am pretty sure he still maintains Boost.

Answer (score 0):

Core should support .gz for CSS & JS. This requires .htaccess rules though. For core they should already be included.

Looks like I never got around to gzip for Boost for 7.x. You can follow the issue here
http://drupal.org/node/1416214

Comment: My statement from [#54](https://drupal.org/comment/7268440#comment-7268440) still applies: "I think the patch from #53 should get in."